# PostgreSQL ODBC Connection VB .NET Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I receive the following error attempting to employ an ODBC connection to connect to a PostgreSQL DB

```
Error: {"ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"}
```

- IDE: Visual Studio 2019
- Language: Visual Basic .Net
- PostgreSQL DB VersionL 10.0

[PostgreSQL ODBC Connection][1]
I have created a SUCCESSFUL 64bit connection to my PostgresSQL with the 64bit ODBC adapter.

My code to test the connection:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim connectionString As String = ""
        connectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL}; Server=localhost; Port=5432; Database=dvdrental2; Uid=postgres; Pwd=xxxxxx"
        Dim cnn As OdbcConnection
        cnn = New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            cnn.Open()
            MsgBox("Connection Open!")
            cnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can not open connection!")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

I understand an ODBC connection is not the best means to connect to a PostgreSQL DB; however, I was curious about implementing this type of connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim connectionString As String = ""
        connectionString = "DSN=PostgreSQL; Server=localhost; Port=5432; Database=dvdrental; Uid=postgres; Pwd=your_pwd"
        Dim cnn As OdbcConnection
        cnn = New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            cnn.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "Select * From city"
            Dim ds As DataSet = GetTableData(connectionString, SQL)
            MsgBox("Connection Open!")
            cnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can not open connection!")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Function GetTableData(ByVal i_cs As String, ByVal sql As String) As DataSet
        ' Create and Initialize as Dataset 
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        ' Create a OdbcConnection
        Using conn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(i_cs)
            Try
                ' Open the OdbcConnection
                conn.Open()
                ' Create a read object of type OdbcDataAdapter
                Dim read As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn)
                ' Fill the DataSet using OdbcDataAdapter
                read.Fill(ds)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
            Finally
                ' Close the Connection
                conn.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
        Return ds
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).